# Process Filtering with Fiddler

Tags: filtering, process, fiddler

Is there a way to filter out certain processes in Fiddler?  Its very noisy currently, and I don't want it to show just one process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter Fiddler traffic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098877/filter-fiddler-traffic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically a duplicate of [Filter Fiddler traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098877/filter-fiddler-traffic) .  Just go to the Filters tab in Fiddler and then the "Client Process" fieldset and then choose "Show only traffic from " and choose the appropriate process.

Answer (score 33):

The built-in `Show only traffic from` option is useful if your process never exits and always has the same PID. In my case, my HTTP client was starting and exiting frequently, so I added this custom FiddlerScript.

Go to `Rules > Customize Rules...` to start editing `CustomRules.js`.

**Add this inside the Handlers class**

```js
class Handlers
{
    RulesString("&Process filter", true)
    RulesStringValue(0, "&Chrome", "chrome")
    RulesStringValue(1, "&Firefox", "firefox")
    RulesStringValue(2, "&Internet Explorer", "iexplore")
    RulesStringValue(3, "&Opera", "opera")
    RulesStringValue(4, "&PhantomJS", "phantomjs")
    RulesStringValue(5, "&Custom...", "%CUSTOM%")
    public static var sProcessName: String = null;

    // leave the rest of the Handlers class as-is
}
```

**Add this inside the OnBeforeRequest function**

```js
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    if (null != sProcessName) {
        var processInfo = oSession["X-PROCESSINFO"];
        if(!processInfo || !processInfo.StartsWith(sProcessName + ":")){
            oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
            FiddlerObject.StatusText = " Process filter: " + sProcessName;
        }
    }

    // leave the rest of the OnBeforeRequest function as-is
}
```

Fiddler will apply your changes as soon as you save the `CustomRules.js` file.

To use, go to `Rules > Process Filter` and choose a browser, or use `Custom` and type in your executable's basename (e.g. `iexplore`).

Filtering applies to requests that start after you choose a process. Previous requests and Fiddler Composer requests are not affected.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I'll have to try this.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a pretty common issue, so I'm a little surprised in the Filters interface they don't just let us use wildcards like "python:*". Or filter from multiple client processes for that matter. Something for the next update, maybe.

Comment: This solution might need to be edited since RulesStringValue's like these already appear in the latest default scripts. Maybe they took a page from this answer. In my case, my goal was just to show anything from a process beginning with python or pythonw, and I accomplished that with a modified version of the second snippet only (note that you'll need sProcessName so you might want to define that on your own).

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  With browsers having multiple processes the built in option to target only one specific process by PID is not very helpful.