# Fiddler not capturing traffic from browsers

Tags: fiddler

I've been using Fiddler for quite a while, but all of a sudden it no longer captures internet traffic.  I'm on Chrome 29 and Fiddler v4.4.5.1.  I've checked all filters and rules and nothing is on.  I've deleted my rules file, turned on and off capture traffic, and a few other things with no luck.  I even uninstalled and re-installed Fiddler to see if that would help but to no avail.

What am I missing?

[Follow Up]:

- Troubleshoot Filters has no effect.
- I see no activity in the log tab beyond "Fiddler Running..."
- I've tried multiple browsers and none show internet traffic in fiddler
- `http://localhost.fiddler:8888/` does not work
- `http://127.0.0.1:8888` works and shows the fiddler echo service.

Comment: I found this article in disabling the filter helpful (I had setup weeks ago when I last used fiddler) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098877/filter-fiddler-traffic

Comment: I had the same issue. When I request something from 127.0.0.1 it works, but if I request from localhost, it doesn't. It seems to be due to a proxy setting, where for the loopback address no proxy is being used, which makes Fiddler unable to inspect the traffic.

I've temporarily solved this by only requesting from 127.0.0.1, or changing my hosts file to use another alias other than "localhost".

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Not sure if this is relevant but I had the same problem with Fiddler after the last update (v2.4.5.0).  I turned all filters off but still wasn't picking up any traffic.  When I unchecked Use Filters on the filters tab, however, all traffic was picked up as normal.  I'm still trying to figure out how I can use filters when just checking Use Filters box causes all traffic to be blocked.

Comment: On the Help menu, choose Troubleshoot Filters. Look to see which filter you have set that's hiding your traffic.

Comment: there's like this little capturing node in the bottom left that you sometimes need to press to start capturing.

Comment: @Thomas Glick. U still can point your application to use the Fiddler proxy instead of the regular WinInet method.

Comment: One thing I found, when I copied all my settings to a new computer, and reinstalled fiddler, it picked up my old filters -- so make sure you don't have old filters blocking your view.

Comment: I had similar issue with Fiddler V5.0, under Filters tabe "Show only Internet explorer Traffic" was checked by default. After unchecking the box I was able to capture Chrome traffic.

Comment: Unchecked it and now I can see the traffic!  Thanks!

Answer (score 102):

I had the same problem, but it turned out to be a chrome extension called **hola** (or **Proxy SwitchySharp**), that messed with the proxy settings. Removing Hola fixed the problem

Comment: same for me. I disabled the extension and it worked.

Comment: When I wanted to chech the Proxy settings, Chrome told me that an extension is managing my proxy settings. After disabling ZenMate Fiddler worked as expected.

Comment: for me Disabling AdBlocker and proxy sharper worked.

Comment: This solved my issue. I just tuned 'Hola' off (instead  of removing it) and Fiddler started to capture traffic immediately from Chrome.

Comment: This had me banging my head against a brick wall - I even uninstalled Fiddler and reinstalled. Turned out it was Hola that was proxying my traffic so fiddler couldn't see it.

Comment: I use tunnelbear extension and even though it was switched off, it still blocked fiddler out

Comment: Same here. The extension I had to disable was 'Proxy List'.

Comment: Same here, maybe not completly removig, but power it down (disabling) the extension, since Hola itself proxies the web traffic.

Comment: Same here. I had chrome extension that update proxy settings for access to blocked in my country sites,

Comment: In my case it is not Hola(:D) , it is Hotspot Shield Free VPN Proxy.

Comment: Mine was SwitchyOmega. Disabled it and back up and running.

Comment: same.. Disabled. Working

Comment: Same for DotVPN - extension only has to be enabled as an extension, not actively switched on and proxying, for the problem to happen. (Can be disabled as an extension, but not fully removed, to fix it.)

Answer (score 35):

1. Use Help > Troubleshoot Filters to make sure the traffic isn't getting hidden unexpectedly.
2. Look in the **Log** tab to see if there's a note about Chrome Group Policy hardcoding the proxy.
3. Update your question to mention whether other browsers' traffic is captured.
4. Visit `http://localhost.fiddler:8888/` in Chrome; What if anything do you see?
5. Visit `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` in Chrome; What if anything do you see?

If you find that steps #1 - #4 don't show anything, this means that Fiddler is unable to set your system proxy information; this might be caused by security or VPN software. (Group Policy can also prevent setting, but Fiddler will *usually* warn you if this is the case).

When Fiddler is capturing, click Tools > WinINET Options > LAN Settings and see whether the proxy is set properly (should point at `127.0.0.1:8888`). If not, you might try running Fiddler elevated (as Administrator) to see if it makes a difference. It *may* be helpful to collect a trace using SysInternals' Process Monitor tool, filtered to **Registry** operations on the **ProxyServer** registry key.

If step #5 doesn't show anything, this means that you have a firewall or some other software interfering with connections to Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I've updated my original post with answers to your questions.

Comment: I'm running Parallels.  When I attempt to change my LAN proxy settings it never takes and always resets to "Auto detect settings".  This is on the same Win7 virtual machine that used to run Fiddler just fine.

Comment: Ah, fascinating. Which version of Parallels? Perhaps this is a feature of the Parallels environment. If you set your host's proxy settings to point at 127.0.0.1:8888, do those end up mirrored inside the VM? Maybe see http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/wl/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/29577.htm

Comment: I don't suppose you have any tips if it works fine in everything other than Chrome - #4 not working, everything else fine?

Comment: Another cause for Chrome traffic not showing up is the `--no-proxy-server` command line parameter, which instructs Chrome to completely ignore any proxy configuration.

Comment: try running Fiddler elevated (as Administrator) did the trick!

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the same issue with https and solved it by checking the HTTPS Decryption

- Goto Fiddler Options -> HTTPS
- Check 'Decrypt HTTPS traffic'

Comment: Thanks, it worked
For those who are getting "unable to configure windows to trust Fiddler root certificate" on this step follow this:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/i-cannot-trust-this-root-certificate-in-win10

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue with Firefox. The solution was to set the proxy settings to "system proxy settings". Fiddler can only capture traffic that goes through its proxy server. Capturing was stopped because a few days ago I was tinkering with the Firefox proxy settings for another project.

It follows that using Chrome you should also check the browser proxy settings in case of problems with capturing traffic with Fiddler.

[Read more about this on the Fiddler site](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-04-01/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler)

Comment: that worked for me too. Firefox was set to "No Proxy". Switching it to "Use system proxy settings" worked.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had previously been using "Manual Proxy Configuration" in Firefox with my company's proxy settings specified.

Answer (score 6):

```
What worked for me is to reset the fiddler https certificate and recreate it.

Fiddler version V4.6XXX 

Fiddler menu-> Tools-> Telerick Fiddler Options... 
Second tab- HTTPS-> Action -> Reset All Certificate
```

[image]

Once you do that, again check the check box(Decrypt HTTPS certificate)

Comment: thanks, this does work for me, I searched many times to solve this issue but you did it :)

Comment: This is also what worked for me. It's like the certificate needed a reboot.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and resolved it by running Fiddler with elevated privileges (aka, Run As Administrator)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, when i disabled chrome extension called **ZenMate Proxy extension** that fixed the problem

Comment: I had the same problem using Tunnel Bear.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. I finally gave up. Reset Chrome's browser settings to default. Uninstalled then reinstalled Fiddler. After that, everything worked.

Comment: same for me... nothing worked except uninstalling and reinstalling

Answer (score 3):

I too faces similar problem, but once I did the below settings, everything was working fine(While working on other application, I selected 'No Proxy' setting in browser which I forgot to revert.Hence, got this problem)

- In Fiddler, Goto **Teleric Fiddler Options->Gateway** , then select 'Use System Proxy (recommended)' radio button and click on 'OK' button and restart Fiddler
- In your Browser(for ex: firefox), Goto Options->Advanced->Network->Settings then select 'Use system proxy settings' radio button and click on OK
- Now try accessing any URL from that browser, and observe they are being recorded in Fiddler(If you have applied filters, even they will start working)

Hope this helps..

Get back to me with any other problems

Answer (score 3):

After hours of googling, reading, uninstalling, and facepalming!
It turned out that a chrome extension for VPN was handling the proxy settings for Chrome!

Betternet to be more specific!

Disabling it, solved my problem.

To make sure that no extension is overriding Chrome's settings, check the proxy settings in Chrome settings page. For me it showed me a message, that says: "Betternet is handling the proxy settings."

Comment: Not just betternet, anykind of vpn extension should be disabled. Open browser settings > search "proxy". disable there

Comment: @abitcode it is kind of what I meant by 
"To make sure it is not the problem, check the proxy settings for Chrome itself. For me it showed me a message, that says: "Betternet is handling the proxy settings."

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is really late, and probably not relevant to what the submitter had 3 years ago, but I found another possible reason why people may not get Fiddler to work, specifically in an Enterprise environment.

We are in the middle of releasing Fiddler.  For my company, we are not allowed to download apps and install ourselves. We have to request IT to approve it and install it via ordering it from a software "Store" here at the company.

To get Fiddler to be available to "order" from that "store", we have to test on test machines.  During testing, we could not get Fiddler to update the IE11 proxy settings.  When I installed Fiddler myself, it would work, but when I had IT install it using the authorized install channels (what we were testing for), it would not work.  Even when we try with users with Local Admin rights, and Run As Administrator, no luck.

At first we thought it was a Group Policy thing, but looking into it, it wasn't the case.

**It turns out the IT people wrapped Fiddler in a VMWare ThinApp wrapper**, an invisible VM sandbox to wrap the app inside of.  I don't know what the benefits are of ThinApp, but **it prevented Fiddler from being able to update the Proxy settings if IE11**.  When you enable capturing, and open WinINET options in Fiddler, it would show the Proxy settings updated.  But when you opened IE11 Connection Settings, the proxy was not updated.  Makes sense.

So the IT folks decided to release it as a "fat app" (that's what they called it) and now it works like a charm.

Just wanted to get this on the internet so that people are aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I thought my issue was solved through the `WinINET Options`. Below are the steps that fixed my Chrome traffic finally being picked up in Fiddler:

From Fiddler -> Tools -> WinINET Options -> LAN settings -> Make sure `Automatically detect settings` is checked.

However, what I just found out later was that the PAC script was resetting these options everytime I fired up Fiddler. The real solution was goto Fiddler -> Tools -> Options -> Connections -> Uncheck `Use PAC Script`. This solved it for good. Below is a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution if you don't mind losing your Fiddler configuration.

To solve this, I had to delete manually the folder ../Documents/Fiddler2 which for whatever reason was not getting removed even after uninstalling and then reinstalling Fiddler. I'm on Fiddler 5.0, build from 03 November 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, in all browsers (IE, Chrome, FF).  Upon startup the Fiddler Log tab showed the following:

"!WARNING Fiddler has detected that system or domain Group Policy has set ProxySettingsPerUser to 0. Unless Fiddler is run Elevated (e.g. Run As Administrator), it may not capture traffic from Internet Explorer and other programs. Current process IS running Elevated."

I'm in a huge corporate environment, with no connection to or info about group policy changes; it apparently just got applied one day.  Thanks, bureaucracy :)

Anyway, that led me to messing around with IE proxy settings.  Changing it from Automatic to 127.0.0.1 on port 8888 (the default configured port in Fiddler) worked.  Kind of a pain, though, because I have to set it each time to override the group policy setting.  And then I get cert errors, which is a known thing because Fiddler uses it's own,  untrusted cert . . . and the beat goes on . . .

Comment: Update:  This was a problem only with IE 8 (yes, IE 8, boo, current corporate standard).  Works fine in IE 10, Fiddler correctly / automagically changes the proxy settings during use and sets it back to the previous settings upon exit.

Answer (score 1):

For me i tried everything on here and eventually it boiled down to a *corporate* *proxy* that kept on ***resetting*** the ***INET Settings***.

I worked my way down the list of suggestions but in the end turned out to be the proxy settings. I had hunch about it but i wanted to be thorogh about it before going to 'IT' and saying can i have local *bindows* proxy settings override please?

I asked for the proxy management software to be removed and then within a second fiddler started working. If you cannot override the proxy settings in Internet Properties then fiddler will never work.

Answer (score 1):

Russian, this info for you!
Fiddler didn't capture Chrome traffic because I had installed Antizapret Chrome addon for access blocked by Russian government sites. I removed it and now all works.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Glick said, the latests versions of Fiddler2 works ok with all major browsers. But beware, there's a "Show only Internet Explorer traffic filter" in the filters sections, just disable that one and everything should work as expected, including other filters.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is related to `WCF` client (this may also include other clients but i'm not sure). 
The client can be configured not to use the machine default proxy, which makes the client/application bypass Fiddler capture.

For further reading: [What is the purpose of usedefaultwebproxy in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967758/what-is-the-purpose-of-usedefaultwebproxy-in-wcf).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Chrome extension called **GeoProxy** - even though proxy was disabled, it still took the traffic away and stopped fiddler from seeing it. Disabling the extension resolved the issue.
I'm guessing this will be an issue with any proxy extension.

(This was meant just as a comment for Claus' response above, which set me on the right path - but apparently I have enough reputation to answer, but not to comment...)

Answer (score 0):

1. Might be you have selected non browsers as an option
2. Select Web browsers instead of non browsers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `Capture Traffic` enabled by making sure it's checked under `File`.

It's sadly too easy to press `F12` by mistake with `Fiddler` focused and disable the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. The solution was to remove proxy from Chrome settings. Also you could have an extension that use proxy. Try to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

For it was betternet extension was causing issue. I think any kind of proxy extension installed on Chrome causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to hide the requests from the Fiddler's UI by using the `FiddlerScript` feature. So something like

[image]

```
   if (!oSession.host.StartsWith("localhost:")) {
       oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
   }
```

[image]