# Fiddler suddenly cannot capture anything from broswers

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, fiddler

Fiddler had worked well on my laptop, but all of a sudden it cannot capture anything from my browsers. I have no ideas about what I have done may cause this problem.

The version of my fiddler is v4.6.0.5, it cannot capture http requests from all of my browsers, chrome, IE and Edge. My system is Windows 10.

I've carefully read the webpage [Fiddler not capturing traffic from browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644601/fiddler-not-capturing-traffic-from-browsers)
However, solutions works well for others do not work in my situations.

- I've tried reinstalled fiddler and reset chrome hundreds of times
- http://localhost.fiddler:8888/ cannot be found
- http://127.0.0.1:8888 returns "This page returned a HTTP/200 response 
  Originating Process Information: chrome:79748"
- I didn't use any filters
- I have no extensions on chrome and close all kinds of VPN software.
- I've checked 'Decrypt HTTPS traffic'

Anybody knows how can I solve the problem? Thank you!

I found that some of the software's http request is captured. It seems like that only the browsers' requests are not captured.
I temporarily use the developer tools in chrome for replacement(Ctrl+Shift+I, choose "NetWork"). It can capture the requests missed in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Your output indicates that:

1. Fiddler is running, and
2. It isn't blocked by a firewall or other software
3. Fiddler is not set as your system's proxy

On Fiddler's `File` menu, does the `Capture traffic` item have a checkmark next to it? While Fiddler is running, if you click `Tools` > `WinINET Options` > `LAN Settings`, what do you see?

Do you have any third-party antivirus software installed? Is this machine under the control of Group Policy (e.g. on a corporate network)?

If you start Chrome like so: `chrome --proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8888`, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!   1. Capture traffic item does have a checkmark next to it.

Comment: 2. In LAN Settings, there are three check boxes, all of them don't have checkmarks. 3.I do have a antivirus software installed, Fiddler still cannot work after I shut the antivirus software down. 4. I Work in my company's network, but fiddler works on some of my colleagues' machines.

Comment: I am not sure that if "chrome --proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8888" is a windows command. I open the command prompt as administrator, enter the chrome directory and type "chrome --proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8888". It opens a chrome page for me, and sadly, Fiddler still capture nothing.