# How to Save the Filters in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

When i find the Tariff how to save the filter list  for the next reboot ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZEj.jpg

Comment: share your code and error here in text format

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZEj.jpg @VedPrakash

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler does not presently offer that feature. Vote here https://fiddler.ideas.aha.io/ideas/FID-I-114

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the method from [Filter Fiddler Traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098967/5749914).

Typically when using Fiddler you should use the Filters tab or FiddlerScript and specify exactly what you want to see in Fiddler. Filters will be saved when restarting Fiddler.

Also, in addition to being able to save the filter, I find that **whitelisting** what I want to see (Filters) is more convenient and effective than **blacklisting** what I don't want to see (Filter Now). You will usually not be able to filter away all the many types of requests that you don't care about, and are probably only interested in a couple types of requests. So just specify those.

Comment: and now under actions button exists additional save/load filters options